# How to add custom formio component to form manager

Tags: html, angular, typescript, formio

I created  custom formio component and i have form manager where i can show list of forms. On this when click on create form it showing one form builder i have to merge my custom form component into that form builder. With this i can edit,delete and save my custom formio component...

Can any one help me in this issue...

Here is my code...

customFormioComponent.ts

```js
 Formio.builder(document.getElementById('builder'), {}, {
      builder: {
        custom: {
          title: 'Custom',
          weight: 0,
          components: {
            address: {
              title: 'Address',
              key: 'address',
              icon: 'fa fa-th-list'
            }
           }
          },
             basic: {
          default: false,
        },
         editForm: {
        select: [
          {
            key: 'api',
            ignore: true
          },
         }
```

customFormioComponent.html

```
    <form-builder id="builder"></form-builder>
```

formManager.module.ts

```js
  RouterModule.forChild(FormManagerRoutes({
            formIndex: ManagerComponent,
            formCreate:CustomFormioComponent
        }))
    ],
    declarations: [
        ManagerComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        ManagerComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        FormManagerService,
        {
            provide: FormManagerConfig, useValue: {
                tag: 'common',
                includeSearch: true,
                saveDraft: true
            }
        }
    ]
```

formManager.component.html

```html
  <formio-grid *ngIf="auth.authenticated" 
              [formio]="service.formio" 
              [gridType]="'form'" 
              [query]="{tags: config.tag, type: 'form'}"
              (rowAction)="onAction($event)" 
              (rowSelect)="onSelect($event)" 
              [createText]="'Create Form'" 
              (createItem)="onCreateItem()">
            </formio-grid>
```